# express .get method callback function problem

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling, router

code for tour.route.js :

```
app.get(tour_controller.getTourById)

tour_controller.js
getTourById = handler.getOne(TourModel);
```

handler.js

```
exports.getOne = (Model, popOptions) => {
   catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
      let query = Model.findById(req.params.id);
      if (popOptions) {`your text`
         query = query.populate(popOptions);
      }
      const docs = await query;
      if (!docs) {
         return next(
            new apiError('No documents found with ID: ' + req.params.id, 404)
         );
      }
      res.status(200).json({
         status: 'succeed!',
         data: docs,
      });
   });
};
```

[problem that displays during npm start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiTZY.png)

I stuck here,
the same thing works for .post, .patch and .delete method but it shows error for .get method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to return

```
exports.getOne = (Model, popOptions) => {
   return catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
      // ...
   });
};
```